# Immediate function: passing an argument that may be undefined

Tags: javascript

How can I pass an object to an immediate function not knowing if that object is defined or not?

```
(function(test) {
    // an exception is thrown: test is not defined.
})(test || {});
```

Comment: use `window["test"]` if it's a global

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Because values like empty string, `NaN`, `0`, and `null` are also *falsy*, not just `undefined` values.

Comment: Also it would throw an exception. `if(window.test)` should be used (outside the function) if anything.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: More to the point, because it has the same problem the OP's code has: If `test` is completely *undeclared*, it throws an exception. The OP's code would be fine (and relying on falsiness) if `test` were declared but had a falsey value, but they've said it's throwing, which tells us the variable is undeclared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long, safe, and specific form of this check would be:

```
(function(test) {
    // an exception is thrown: test is not defined.
})(typeof test !== 'undefined' ? test : {});
```

The [typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) does not throw if the variable is undefined.

The shorthand equivalent form would be:

```
var test = test || {};
(function(test) {
    // an exception is thrown: test is not defined.
})(test);
```

which defines `test` if it was not previously defined (or was falsy). This works because the identifier is technically declared with `var test` but not yet initialized (or overwritten), so you can access the previous value (if any) or use the uninitialized value.

Comment: The `var` version isn't a shorthand of the other because it can't be used an expression.

Comment: *"The shorthand equivalent form..."* **isn't** equivalent, because A) It creates a variable in the enclosing scope if there isn't one there already, whereas the first form above (and in all the other answers) doesn't; and B) It tests *specifically* for an undeclared variable or one containing the value `undefined`, whereas the second form will overwrite any *falsey* value (not just `undefined`).

Answer (score 3):

You need to test whether `test` is undefined before accessing it:

```
(function(test) {

})(typeof(test) == 'undefined' ? {} : test);
```

Comment: `typeof` is an operator, not a function; no need for `()`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I prefer it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the existence of a variable, you can use the [`typeof` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3):

```
(function(test) {
    // ...
})(typeof test != 'undefined' ? test : {});
```